# How to divide all float numbers in a file?

Tags: python

I'm new with python, haven't read all the docs yet, I have a file contains x,y values and I want to divide all these x,y values with 1000 or move the decimal 3 digits. Sample of the file:

```
TP_NET 537.534 768.500   MFO2_CAN1TX_EVENT1 TOP
TP_NET 518.000 815.500   MFO1_CAN1RX TOP
TP_NET 416.000 829.500   CON_SPI1_MISO BOTTOM
```

I would like the output file to be

```
TP_NET .537534 .768500   MFO2_CAN1TX_EVENT1 TOP
TP_NET .518000 .815500   MFO1_CAN1RX TOP
TP_NET .416000 .829500   CON_SPI1_MISO BOTTOM
```

I could use Excel to do this very easily but I'm learning python. So, here's what I wrote and it has errors everywhere.

```
import re
import numpy as np
num = 1000
with open('tp') as f, open('tp_mils','w') as f1:
list = re.findall('\d*?\.\d+', f.readline())
new_list = np.divide(list, num)
f1.writelines(new_list)
```

This is the failure:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "float.py", line 6, in <module>
    new_list = np.divide(list, num)
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.      
"It has errors everywhere" is (1) not a problem specification and (2) indicates that you need to work through tutorials on Python syntax and semantics, rather than *specific* help from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "float.py", line 6, in <module>
    new_list = np.divide(list, num)
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: "list" is a list of strings you have to convert to floats first.

Comment: The indentation of your code is broken, and naming a variable `list` is a terrible idea, be careful. Aside from that, I think @Prune covered everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to over-complicate things by using the `re` or `numpy` modules to do this:

```
divisor = 1000
with open('tp') as inp, open('tp_mils', 'w') as outp:
    for line in inp:
        row = line.strip().split(maxsplit=3)
        # Replace the second and third columns with scaled values.
        row[1:3] = ['{:.6f}'.format(float(value)/divisor) for value in row[1:3]]
        outp.write(' '.join(row[:3]) + '   ' + ' '.join(row[3:]) + '\n')
```

Contents of `tp_mils` file afterwards:

```
TP_NET 0.537534 0.768500   MFO2_CAN1TX_EVENT1 TOP
TP_NET 0.518000 0.815500   MFO1_CAN1RX TOP
TP_NET 0.416000 0.829500   CON_SPI1_MISO BOTTOM
```

In the event you don't know which columns will contain float numbers in advance, *then* it would make sense to use the `re` module to identify which ones they are:

```
import re

divisor = 1000
pattern = re.compile(r'\d*?\.\d+')

with open('tp') as inp, open('tp_mils', 'w') as outp:
    for line in inp:
        row = (value if not pattern.match(value) else
               '{:.6f}'.format(float(value)/divisor) for value in line.split())
        outp.write(' '.join(row) + '\n')
```

Result:

```
TP_NET 0.537534 0.768500 MFO2_CAN1TX_EVENT1 TOP
TP_NET 0.518000 0.815500 MFO1_CAN1RX TOP
TP_NET 0.416000 0.829500 CON_SPI1_MISO BOTTOM
```

Comment: what if I have a combined file with these x, y are in different columns, then we need to use the re.findall (float)? and how would I write that? some blocks x, y would be in columns 4,5 for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You neglected to convert your found fields to `float`.  I traced the problem with a simple `print`, after removing the file input from the problem space.  Each line of input yields two of output: a Python `list` and the resulting `numpy` array.

NOTE: Do *not* "shadow" a built-in type with a local variable, as you did with `list`.

```
import re
import numpy as np
num = 1000
infile = [
    "TP_NET 537.534 768.500   MFO2_CAN1TX_EVENT1 TOP",
    "TP_NET 518.000 815.500   MFO1_CAN1RX TOP",
    "TP_NET 416.000 829.500   CON_SPI1_MISO BOTTOM",
]

for line in infile:
    nums = [float(x) for x in re.findall('\d*?\.\d+', line)]
    print(nums)
    new_list = np.divide(nums, num)
    print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[537.534, 768.5]
[0.537534 0.7685  ]
[518.0, 815.5]
[0.518  0.8155]
[416.0, 829.5]
[0.416  0.8295]
```